# Branch.io sharesheet doesn't work, without any errors or bugs

Tags: branch, share, deep-linking, branch.io

There no bug report I can attach. It just simply doesn't work. I click the share, and regardless which option I choose (copy, whatsapp, messanger etc) nothing happens. It just folds back to the bottom and does nothing. If I try to past after clicking the copy, it pastes the previous thing I copied (meaning, it didn't copy the share link at all).

This is my code:

```
    lp = LinkProperties()

    buo.listOnGoogleSearch(viewHolder.root.context)

    share.setOnClickListener {
        val ss = ShareSheetStyle(activity, "Republic invite", "Join me in this republic.")
            .setCopyUrlStyle(activity.resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send), "Copy", "Added to clipboard")
            .setMoreOptionStyle(activity.resources.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search), "Show more")
            .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK)
            .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK_MESSENGER)
            .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.WHATS_APP)
            .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.TWITTER)
            .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
            .setSharingTitle("Share With")

        buo.showShareSheet(activity, lp, ss, object : Branch.BranchLinkShareListener {
            override fun onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {}
            override fun onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {}
            override fun onLinkShareResponse(sharedLink: String, sharedChannel: String, error: BranchError) {}
            override fun onChannelSelected(channelName: String) {
                firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("community_shared_$channelName", null)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you see the same error after you change the codes as the following examples?

```
    val buo = BranchUniversalObject()
    val lp = LinkProperties()


    val ss = ShareSheetStyle(this@MainActivity, "Check this out!", "This stuff is awesome: ")
        .setCopyUrlStyle(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send),
            "Copy",
            "Added to clipboard"
        )
        .setMoreOptionStyle(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search),
            "Show more"
        )
        .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK)
        .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.EMAIL)
        .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.MESSAGE)
        .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.HANGOUT)
        .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
        .setSharingTitle("Share With")

    buo.showShareSheet(this, lp, ss, object : Branch.BranchLinkShareListener {
        override fun onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {}
        override fun onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {}
        override fun onLinkShareResponse(
            sharedLink: String,
            sharedChannel: String,
            error: BranchError
        ) {
        }

        override fun onChannelSelected(channelName: String) {}
    })
```

Please contact [support@branch.io](http://support@branch.io) if you still need our assistance for this issue.

Comment: Still getting problems.
Is there a way for me to create my own share sheet? As I don't like the design of it too.